# Is there any barcode reader that can be integrated with java to get the barcode value?

Tags: java

Currently i am working on a project , in which in module , the barcode reads a particular barcode from product and store its value in our project.

We require a barcode reader  whose value can be read using java.

Please help me in determining the a compatible barcode reader and its api for java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, most barcode readers present themselves as a keyboard, and reading the code sends the appropriate message as if the code had been typed.  Is this not enough?

Comment: There are also some that work over a serial connection and don't mimic a keyboard. In any event, no special Java API is needed for any of those.

Answer (score 4):

You can try Zxing an open source tool for java which enables both barcode generation and barcode reading.